# Autocomplete Textbox from database MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my textboxfor field which select the data from role table from the database
i need this textboxfor field make a autocomplete with starting character.

### Sample:

MVC code:

> This JsonResult in the UsersControl

```
 public JsonResult GetRoles(string Prefix)
    {
        var RoleListVal = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Deleted == false)
            .Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(Prefix))
            .Select(r => new { Name = r.Name, ID = r.RoleID }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(RoleListVal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

cshtml Code:

> This the JS and the HTML5 TextBoxFor:

```js
$("#keywords-manual").autocomplete({
        source: "/Users/GetRoles",
        minLength: 1
    })
```

```html
<div class="form-inline">
            @Html.Label("Role :")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "keywords-manual" })
</div>
```

I don't why isn't working!

Comment: Try to return an array instead of json

Comment: *why isn't working!* is off topic

Comment: Akshay -not understand you

Comment: Div - i don't know why

Comment: Your server side method is hitting or not when you type in autocomplete? If it is hitting then  RoleListVal is filled with values ?

Comment: If i write any word the autocomplete is not working

Comment: Not hit while write ant word

Comment: @Div how to passing any Prefix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your controller side method looks good.

But issue is while you calling method.

```
    $("#keywords-manual").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetRoles","Users")',
                        data: { Prefix: $('#keywords-manual').val() },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.Name,
                                    description: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Not make anything also

Comment: Not hit the method

Comment: Is it must add any reference to the html page ?

Comment: the link attributes depend on what ?

Comment: Use [HttpPost] for hitting the method

Answer (score -1):

This is how you configure the Autocomplete plug in

On HTML Side:

```
$(function () {
            $("#keywords-manual").autocomplete({
                source: "@Url.Action("GetRoles","Users")",
                minLength: 1
            })
                   });
```

On the controller side:

```
public JsonResult GetRoles(string term)
    {
        var RoleListVal = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Deleted == false)
            .Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(term))
            .Select(r => new { label = r.Name, id = r.RoleID,value=r.RoleID }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(RoleListVal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: @Div the autocomplete plugin does that automatically

Comment: @AhmedHossamAlhansy It may have a syntax error, but you should be able to fix it, if not, just put the error message and I will let you know how

Comment: @AhmedHossamAlhansy Open the dev toolbar, then type something in the textbox, check the network tab and see if it fires a request to the backend or not and inspect the requested URL and query string parameter, check also if the backend method in the controller is called or not and if it is called, check the results and also make sure the console tab in the dev toolbar is not showing any errors, if it shows any error, please copy it here